# Select count from referenced column

Tags: database, sqlite

I have the following tables:

```
  CREATE TABLE ips(
    ip TEXT PRIMARY KEY,    
    blocked INTEGER(1) DEFAULT 0
  );
  
  CREATE TABLE acc(
    ip TEXT NOT NULL,
    time INTEGER(4) DEFAULT (CAST(strftime('%s','now') AS INT)),
    FOREIGN  KEY(ip) REFERENCES ips(ip) ON DELETE CASCADE  
  );
```

How can I get a list ips from the first table that have `blocked = 1` and 0 associated rows in the "acc" tables?

`SELECT ip FROM ips WHERE blocked = 1 AND ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use left outer join.

example :
select *
from ips a left outer join acc b on a.ip =b.ip
where a.blocked = 0 and b.ip is null

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select i.* from ips i
where i.blocked = 1
and not exists (select 1 from acc a where a.ip = i.ip)
```

or if you want only the column `ip` use `EXCEPT`:

```
select ip from ips where blocked = 1
except
select ip from acc
```